# Не работает простейший алгоритм

Tags: c++, указатели, память

Есть простейший алгоритм на c++, который заполняет и выводит двухмерный динамический массив числами от 1 до n*m, но не работает с некоторыми входными данными. проверял с значениями 12 34, 12 4, 5 8, 5, 9 - не работает, просто ничего не выводит. Пытался повторно ввести 5, 9, заработало, но с ошибкой: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите найти ошибку

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    int** matr = new int* [n];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        matr[i] = new int[m];
    }
    int k = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            matr[i][j] = k;
            k++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            cout << matr[i][j]<< " ";
            
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    

    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int** matr = new int* [n];
```

Если уж вы выделили указатели для `n` строк

```
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
```

то почему выделяете память для `m` из них? :)

```
{
    matr[i] = new int[m];
}
```

Так что не работает *не* алгоритм...